# Ajax call returning 500 error in the console in Laravel 5

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I have a form in laravel5 based website , The form looks like this

```
<form id="vcard" action="/targetmodule/variancecard" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="iDPCv9dJIANYxZgwDOLmPzHg7tozMWpe1Yp7SR5R">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Event Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" name="event">
                        <option value="Design Mission India-(South&amp; West)">Design Mission India-(South&amp; West)</option>
                        <option value="Design Mission India-(North &amp; East)">Design Mission India-(North &amp; East)</option>
                        <option value="Design Mission India-(North &amp; East)">Design Mission India-(North &amp; East)</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="empid" value="IDE133">
                    <button type="submit" class="getvariance btn btn-primary " name="submit">Submit</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

The Jquery is Like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.getvariance').on('click',function(event){  

    event.preventDefault();

    data_array = $("#vcard").serialize();


  $.ajax({
        url: '/targetmodule/variancecard',
        type: "post",
        data: data_array,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
      }); 
  });
});
</script>
```

And the Route is as follow

```
Route::post('targetmodule/variancecard','TargetController@variancecard');
```

The TargetController looks like this

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\User;
use App\Deal;
use App\Employee;
use App\Targetassign;
use Session;
use Validator;
class TargetController extends Controller
{
public function variancecard( Request $request ){


    //Getting all post data
    if($request->ajax()) {

   $data = Input::all();

  print_r($data);die;
    }

}
}
```

The **ERROR Log**

```
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#1 E:\ide-invoice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 E:\ide-invoice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 [internal function]: Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#4 E:\ide-invoice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 E:\ide-invoice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession.php(62): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 [internal function]: Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#7 E:\ide-invoice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#8 E:\ide-invoice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#10 E:\ide-invoice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 E:\ide-invoice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#13 E:\ide-invoice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 E:\ide-invoice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(42): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 E:\ide-invoice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#17 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 E:\ide-invoice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 E:\ide-invoice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#20 E:\ide-invoice\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(87): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 E:\ide-invoice\public\index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
```

I am getting 500 error when I submit the form

The error in console

```
POST http://localhost:8000/targetmodule/variancecard 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Any help would be really helpful .

Thanks

Comment: Look at the sever log file. A http code 500 is a internal server error.

Comment: What's in the TargetController ?

Comment: You are asking about in internal server error, but are only providing front-end code. So it is impossible to help you without your backend code
1. What is in your `storage/logs`? 
2. What is in `TargetController@variancecard`?

Comment: As Jens said, this is server related. Odds are it's throwing an error in the backend and returning a 500 error. Potentially you can look at the ajax itself in the network tab. It may provide some useful info either in the header or in the response.

Comment: The 500 (internal server error) means something went wrong on the server's side

Comment: Your action is wrong. Try: TargetController@variancecard

Comment: @Gravy i have updated the controller file

Comment: @Vikram. The fix: You are using `Input::all()`, but are not using it in your controller. Add `use Input;` at the top of your controller. Better solution: You are method injecting a Request object into your `variancecard` method, but you are not using it? Replace `$data = Input::all();` with `$data = $request->all()`.

Comment: add a hidden input in your form named _token with value="{{ csrf_token() }}"

Comment: @KhanShahrukh its already there

Comment: I am sorry I did not see that, but are you explicitly defining the value of the token ?

Comment: @KhanShahrukh no I dumped the form page from the browser in my code I am using `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />` like this .

Answer (score 0):

The fix: Input::all(), which is in the `Global namespace` but your controller is in the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace. Simply add `use Input;` at the top of your controller with the rest of your use statements.

Better solution: You are method injecting a Request object into your variancecard method, but you are not using it? Replace `$data = Input::all();` with `$data = $request->all();`

Either:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\User;
use App\Deal;
use App\Employee;
use App\Targetassign;
use Session;
use Validator;
use Input;

class TargetController extends Controller
{
public function variancecard( Request $request ){


    //Getting all post data
    if($request->ajax()) {

   $data = Input::all();

  print_r($data);die;
    }

}
}
```

Or:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\User;
use App\Deal;
use App\Employee;
use App\Targetassign;
use Session;
use Validator;
class TargetController extends Controller
{
public function variancecard( Request $request ){


    //Getting all post data
    if($request->ajax()) {

   $data = $request->all();

  print_r($data);die;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the 500 error from `storage/logs/your latest log file` or make sure that your `.env` file has the lines `APP_ENV=local` and `APP_DEBUG=true`. Run again and see what the actual 500 error message is.

Comment: Okay I am gonna paste it here

Comment: So from your error log, you have a problem with the `csrf_token`. Please take a look at Kóta Péters answer. Also, it may be worth reading up about http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection